How is the AWG rating of a ribbon cable interpreted?
Suppose a ribbon cable rated 24 AWG. Does the implied current limit apply to each conductor separately or to the overall ribbon if all conductors are used in parallel? Or in other words, how much cross-sectional area of copper will I get in total?
Are there any industry standards which specify this?

why don't you do a comparison to a single wire? .... also, if a 10 conductor ribbon cable is labeled 24 AWG and a 50 conductor ribbon cable is labeled 24 AWG then that tells you something

AWG ("American Wire Gauge") is not a rating, it is a simple reference to the cross-sectional area of the conductors. Just a mechanical dimension (or sum of dimensions in the case of stranded wire). If the ribbon cable is "24 AWG" then I would expect each conductor (or the sum of the strands that make up each conductor) to be nominally 0.205mm^2 cross-sectional area. Stranded wire often doesn't quite add up to the nominal number, but there are tolerances anyway.
The actual safe current through a conductor or array of conductors will depend on the number of conductors, the environment (altitude and temperature, primarily), the current through each, the temperature rating of the insulation and other factors.
There are various standards- some very prescriptive (eg. local codes for domestic wiring) and others that require more data to evaluate. For example, see this document for aircraft- eg. PDF page 50.

Unless I've missed a relevant sentence, the linked PDF says nothing about what I'm asking.

@Boann Correct, and I doubt you'll find anything other than the cable manufacturer's data that specifically addresses ribbon cables. However if you know the temperature rating of the insulation etc. you can infer a reasonable rating for a given environment.

In simple terms, It is the cross-sectional value of each conductor (i.e. one cable on the ribbon). Refer to the datasheet of the cable for more info. For AWG to Current capacity refer to the following link.
https://www.powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm

Usually, in a multi-conductor cable, the current limit is for each conductor.  However if all the conductors are carrying significant current, the current capacity is derated due to heating effects which can degrade insulation and so reduces each conductor's max current capacity.
This is no different than residential or commercial AC (120 V) wiring, where the rated current needs to be derated if multiple cables (like #14 NM) are bundled together.
And there are guidelines, or rules-of-thumb, for figuring out how many conductors you need to carry a particular current.
